# Regex process using cut(Linux)(sh)

Tags: regex, bash, grep, cut, ps

I'm having a problem with regex in using the command sh cute, the problem is that I want to show all processes that start with g and just show the command, but do not know, help me please?

To do this I use the command:

```
ps aux | grep g
```

but this show all process who contains the letter g and **i need who start with g**
and cut the command to get this, for example i get a output of ps

```
root      1012  0.0  0.0   6128   644 tty4     Ss+  16:10   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
```

`1000      4571  0.0  0.0  12724   868 pts/4    S+   19:21   0:00 grep --color=auto g`

And I need get only /sbin/getty because is in path and the command grep.
In definite get all files start with g and cut and cut above so that it is the command and attributes
PD: I need use to get all with the commands grep and cut, and i can't don't use the pgrep.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `awk` will be easier than `cut` to get the right field out.

Comment: I need use the cut for script

Comment: If this is homework, it should have the `homework` tag.

Comment: `grep` uses regexes, `cut` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can't split with `cut` on a regex, a group of spaces in this case.  You can either cut from a certain bytes, or cut by a single character delimiter.  So you can do

```
ps aux | cut -b66- | grep g
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cut:

```
ps -ao command | grep g
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
ps -o "comm" -A | grep -E "^g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
ps -eo command | grep -E '^(|\S*/)g'
```